# Two questions about sphere bundles

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fibre-bundles

I would like to better understand the relationship between different notions of orientable sphere bundle. Let me say that a locally trivial fiber bundle $\pi\colon E\to M$ with fiber $S^n$ and structure group $G$ is a

topological sphere bundle if $G=\mathrm{Homeo}^+(S^n)$,

smooth sphere bundle if $G=\mathrm{Diffeo}^+(S^n)$,

linear sphere bundle if $G=\mathrm{Gl}^+(n,\mathbb{R})$.

It is known that there exist smooth sphere bundles that are not equivalent (as smooth sphere bundles) to linear sphere bundles (see e.g. the following posts here on MO):

[Examples of sphere bundles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116003/examples-of-sphere-bundles)

[Is it true that all sphere bundles are boundaries of disk bundles?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74756/is-it-true-that-all-sphere-bundles-are-boundaries-of-disk-bundles)

For example, in an answer to the second question linked above R. Budney shows that there are smooth sphere bundles over $S^2$ which are not linear. Here comes my first question:

1. Is it possible to construct a smooth sphere bundle over $S^1$ which is not smoothly equivalent to a linear one? One could take an exotic diffeomorphism  $f\colon S^n\to S^n$, and consider the mapping cone of $f$, which is a smooth sphere bundle. Is this bundle linear?

The second question is about topological bundles:

2. Do there exist a topological sphere bundle which is not topologically isomorphic to a linear one (or even to a smooth one)?

Comment: Concerning your second question (topological $\ne$ linear), isn't it what $J$-groups are about?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recall that linear, smooth, and topological $S^k$-bundles over a finite complex $X$ are classified by the sets of homotopy classes $[X, BO_{k+1}]$, $[X, B\mathrm{Diff}(S^k)]$ and  $[X, B\mathrm{Homeo}(S^k)]$. There are obvious maps between the sets, and we are interested in their cokernels.

For example, if $X=S^1$, then the smooth nonlinear bundles are elements of the cokernel of $\pi_1(BO_{k+1})\to \pi_1(B\mathrm{Diff}(S^k))$. By the exact homotopy sequence the cokernel is isomorphic to $\pi_0(\mathrm{Diff}(S^k)/O_{k+1})$. The space $\mathrm{Diff}(S^k)/O_{k+1}$ is simply $\mathrm{Diff}(D^k, \partial)$, the diffeomorphisms of the disk that are the identity on the boundary. The latter space is classically studied, and by results of Smale and Cerf the group $\pi_0(\mathrm{Diff}(D^k, \partial))$ is isomorphic to the group of homotopy $(k+1)$-spheres, and hence it is often nonzero. Thus there are lots of smooth non-linear bundles over a circle.

EDIT: *the crossed out text below is nonsense, and I retract it. What one actually needs is that $\mathrm{Diff}(S^k)\to \mathrm{Homeo}(S^k)$ is not $\pi_i$-surjective for some $i$, and at the moment I do not know any $k, i$ for which this is true.*

<strike>Non-smoothable sphere bundles over spheres also exist because the space $\mathrm{Homeo}(S^k)/\mathrm{Diff}(S^k)$ is not contractible, for otherwise the inclusion $\mathrm{Diff}(S^k)\to \mathrm{Homeo}(S^k)$ would be a $\pi_i$-isomorphism for all $i$, which it is not for some $k$ (this is due to Alexander's trick, see page 3 of the reference 2 below).</strike>

Some references to online sources which you may find useful, and which contains references to the above claims):

1. A. Hatcher's survey: [http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/Diff%28M%292012.pdf](http://www.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/Papers/Diff%28M%292012.pdf)
2. P.L. Antonelli, D. Burghelea,
   P.J. Kahn, http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938372900213
3. D. Crowley, T. Schick: https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.6474